# Google Cloud Vision API (labels), how many possible labels are there?

Tags: machine-learning, google-api, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vision, vision-api

I have been searching for this for hours.. but still cannot get a proper answer.....

Where can I get a full list of labels that Google Cloud Vision API can possibly produce ?

example of google api result ) 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnwut.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the complete list of labels detected by Google Cloud Vision API is not publicly available, and it does not seem like there are any ongoing plans to make it public in the near future. You should understand that the list includes tens of thousands (or even more) possible combinations of words and/or phrases, and Vision API is improved over time, so the amount of labels that can be detected also grows.